# Using php to compare mysql results, then echo differences?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to figure out how I can compare two mysql query results and echo out the differences. Basically I have a database that is comparing state flag characteristics. The user would select 2 states and what I would like is to have the php echo out 3 sets of results (state 1 only, shared characterisics, and state 2 only). My rough code below only echos out characteristics for states 1 and 2. Is there a way that I can compare the query results, so that I get differences between the states, and also shared characteristics.

```
<?php  $query1 = $_GET['query1'];   
       $query2 = $_GET['query2'];  
       $min_length = 2;?>

<!-- state 1 characteristics only -->

<div class="fluid s1charc">

<?php echo "<strong><p>Search results for $query1</strong></p>";?>

<?php if(strlen($query1) >= $min_length){$query1 = htmlspecialchars($query1);
      $query1 = mysql_real_escape_string($query1);
      $raw_results1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM charc_s WHERE `charc_f` ='$query1' ORDER BY FLAG_S") or die(mysql_error());
      if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results1) > 0) { 
      while($results1 = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results1)){

      echo "<table id='iseqchart' class='sortable'>
               <tr valign='middle'>
                   <td ><a href='flag.php?FLAG_ID=".$results1['FLAG_ID']."'><img src='images/".$results1['IMAGE']."'></a></td>
                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
                   <td><strong><font size='3'><a href='flag.php?FLAG_ID=".$results1['FLAG_ID']."' style='color:#100783'>".$results1['FLAG_S']."&nbsp;(".$results1['STATE'].")</strong></a>                 
                   </td>
               </tr>
              </table>";
            }
        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "No results were found";
        }
    }
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo " ".$min_length;
    }
?> 

</div>

<!-- shared characteristics -->
<div class="fluid sharecharc">Shared</div>

<!-- state 2 characteristics only -->
<div class="fluid s2charc">
<?php echo "<strong><p>Search results for $query2</strong></p>"; ?>

<?php  if(strlen($query2) >= $min_length){$query2 = htmlspecialchars($query2); 
       $query2 = mysql_real_escape_string($query2);  
       $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM charc_s WHERE `charc_f` ='$query2' ORDER BY FLAG_S") or die(mysql_error());
       if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0) {  
       while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
       echo "<table id='iseqchart' class='sortable'>
               <tr valign='middle'>
                   <td ><a href='flag.php?FLAG_ID=".$results['FLAG_ID']."'><img src='images/".$results['IMAGE']."'></a></td>
                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
                   <td><strong><font size='3'><a href='flag.php?FLAG_ID=".$results['FLAG_ID']."' style='color:#100783'>".$results['FLAG_S']."&nbsp;(".$results['STATE'].")</strong></a>                
                   </td>
               </tr>
              </table>";
            }
        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "No results were found";
        }  
    }
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo " ".$min_length;
    }
?>

</div>
```

Comment: not sure if this is what you need, but it might help... http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-diff.php
this function will return you every value that does not exist in both arrays.

Comment: using what @TanuelMategi has suggested - you should save the results in an array, then compare the two.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is on the server side.  Make the database do 3 different selects.  The reason is that the server will run the queries a lot faster than the php.  And it will end up in a better user experience.

Only Table A

```
 SELECT * FROM TableA A LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.key = B.key
```

Only Table B

```
 SELECT * FROM TableA A RIGHT JOIN TableB B ON A.key = B.key
```

And in Both Tables

```
 SELECT * FROM TableA A INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.key = B.key
```

From there echo out your results.